# python selenium ログインIDとパスワードをコードの外に別ファイルにして管理したいです。

Tags: python, python3, selenium

#### 前提・実現したいこと

python selenium ログインIDとパスワードをコードの外に別ファイルにして管理したいです。
ネットで調べるとconfigparserとiniを使うとのことで試してみました。
config.iniファイルをデスクトップに置いて、それを読み込みにいくのだと思うのですが上手くいきません。

configparserとiniファイルを使う方法でなくてもいいのですが、やりたいのはIDとPWをコードから外に出して、テキストファイルなどで使用者が管理する方法を取りたいと思っています。
iniファイルの書き方がおかしいのでしょうか？
分かる方お手数ですが教えて下さい。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```
[user]
name     : nnnnnn
password : pppppp
```

#### 試したこと

```
from selenium import webdriver
import configparser

inifile = configparser.ConfigParser()
inifile.read(r'C:\Users\*****\Desktop\config.ini', 'UTF-8')

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")

#driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get('http://www.******.biz/login/index.html') 
elem_username = driver.find_element_by_name('id') 
elem_username.send_keys(inifile.get('user', 'name'))
elem_password = driver.find_element_by_name('passwd')
elem_password.send_keys(inifile.get('user', 'password'))
driver.find_element_by_class_name('alpha').click()

driver.execute_script('close_popup();')
```

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

Python 3.7.3
Windows7
jupyter notebook
chromedriver

Comment: 解決しました！
iniファイルをメモ帳で作ると駄目でした。BOMが付加されてしまったファイルは、エラーになるようです。秀丸で新規で作成したらできました。
http://croppy.net/archives/17

Comment: ぜひ調べて分かったことを **個別の回答** として投稿してみてください。スタック・オーバーフローでは [自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) も歓迎しています。

Answer (score 1):

iniファイルをメモ帳で編集した際、BOMが付加されていたのが原因のようです。
替わりに秀丸でファイルを新規作成することで問題が解決しました。

**参考にしたサイト:**
[「File contains no section headers. file: …」とエラーが表示されTracプロジェクトが開けなくなる](http://croppy.net/archives/17)

---

*この投稿は [@Tani chan さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/61706/python-selenium-%e3%83%ad%e3%82%b0%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3id%e3%81%a8%e3%83%91%e3%82%b9%e3%83%af%e3%83%bc%e3%83%89%e3%82%92%e3%82%b3%e3%83%bc%e3%83%89%e3%81%ae%e5%a4%96%e3%81%ab%e5%88%a5%e3%83%95%e3%82%a1%e3%82%a4%e3%83%ab%e3%81%ab%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e7%ae%a1%e7%90%86%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99#comment67201_61706) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*